# Entity Framework Core with PostgreSQL and SEQUENCE functionality

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, sequence

I am used to the SQL Server world, where if I wanted to create a 'next number' table for use by many sessions, I'd probably use some kind of INT IDENTITY(1,1) AUTO INCREMENT column in a single row table, and just tightly control transactional access to make sure everyone that asked for an ID got a unique next available.

However, I'm working with Entity Framework Core at the moment and PostgreSQL, and have come across the SEQUENCE and nextval functionality. It sounds perfect for this requirement, but I am unclear or unsure what will happen with this table if I try to introduce it to EF Core. I use the Database first method, and generated all my models from existing tables when I started out. If I need to add a new column I just add it manually to my EF code, and if I need to do something more fundamental like a new table, I will re-run the db scaffold EF Core CLI command referencing the specific table as a parameter.

Because this 'SEQUENCE' table - to a SQL server person like me - seems like special PostgreSQL voodoo, can anyone explain *what this table will look like if I try to scaffold it from the database*? Will it just show up as a normal table model/entity? *Will anything special be required* because I'll want to be able to select from this table to get the next available number (sometimes from many sessions in quick succession)?

Answer (score -2):

Postgres Sequences are similar to that of Oracle.
The oracle documentation summarizes it as such:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm#ADMIN11793

Sequences are database objects from which multiple users can generate unique integers. The sequence generator generates sequential numbers, which can help to generate unique primary keys automatically, and to coordinate keys across multiple rows or tables.

Without sequences, sequential values can only be produced programmatically. A new primary key value can be obtained by selecting the most recently produced value and incrementing it. This method requires a lock during the transaction and causes multiple users to wait for the next value of the primary key; this waiting is known as serialization. If developers have such constructs in applications, then you should encourage the developers to replace them with access to sequences. Sequences eliminate serialization and improve the concurrency of an application.